# RMI. Ошибка при запуске сервера

Tags: javascript, java, сервер, rmi

При запуске сервера через пакетный файл, в открывшейся консоли выскакивает вот такая ошибка, может быть кто нибудь знает как это пофиксить? Ошибка следующая: could not find or load main class. com.rmiserver.ServerOperation [image: Error]

После этой ошибки окно закрывается и просто остается черное окно без каких либо надписей.

Comment: Плохо написанный пакетный файл, видимо. Ошибка означает, что Java не может найти класс `com.rmiserver.ServerOperation`.

Comment: Было бы странно, потому что я попытался запустить эту же программу на другом компьютере и все работает. Может есть какая то проблема не связанная с кодом?

Comment: Подозреваю, что на том компьютере кто-то сначала запустил файл `compileEverything.cmd`. А может там где-нибудь прописан `CLASSPATH`. В любом случае, это подтверждает мою теорию о том, что пакетный файл плох.